# Inputs inside multiple forms with no submit button need to be displayed

Tags: python, html, http, flask, web-applications

I'm new here and I'm not at a high programming level...
I have a problem with the developing of a web application using flask and html. In the same html page I have some input boxes (that will be compiled by a user) and their content would be inserted inside a select that initially is empty. In addition I have no submit button and I could not insert it in my app because of the will of my boss. Is there a way to do this?

I've tried searching through the web for hours, but still nothing... Is there someone that could help me?

Comment: Can you clarify a little more how would you like it to work, ideally? Are there a fixed number of inputs on the page or does the user need to be able to add them somehow? At what point does the content get added to the select? (When they press enter, or when the input loses focus, or immediately as they type... something else?)

Answer (score 0):

Add onblur function to input box and write function to insert their content. You can use onfocusout function also.